# Has there been any work done on AI-driven operant conditioning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, research, operant-conditioning

For example, a RL algorithm that gains points when a rat presses a lever and loses points when it dispenses a pellet, water, treat, and/or sugar water. After a few days of controlling the rewards given to a rat, all rewards are stopped and the longer/more times the rat presses the lever before giving up, the higher the score.

This would be a situation in which both the input and the outputs are discrete with very low data density over time and with outputs having very long-term affects on the environment.

What kind of RL architecture would be appropriate here?